# Updating variable property problem for Prism BindableBase

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I am trying to create an application with using Prism Library.  I need certain classes to be informed when a specific property changes, however in my current code my notification event is not firing.  How can I be notified when my property changes?

To reproduce my issue, let's say there is one model, one viewmodel and one view in my application.  My model has objects from classes as shown below:

```
public class SettingsModel : BindableBase
{
    private Controller _controller;
    public Controller Controller
    {
        get { return _controller; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _controller, value); }
    }

    public SettingsModel()
    { 
        Controller = new Controller();
    }
}
```

Let's say Controller class has a property called Language:

```
public class Controller : BindableBase
{
    private Languages _language;
    public Languages Language
    {
        get { return _language; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _language, value);}
    }

    public Controller()
    {
        Language = Languages.English;
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel there is a property called ActiveSettings:

```
private SettingsModel _activeSetting;
public SettingsModel ActiveSetting
{
    get { return _activeSetting; }
    set
    {
        if (SetProperty(ref _activeSetting, value))
        {
            ActiveSettingChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Lastly, in my view, I bound selectedvalue to my variable as it is shown below. I want to inform other classes if ActiveSetting property is changed with using ActiveSettingChanged event. However, when I change value of the combobox, even if I see the Language property of ActiveSetting is changing (with putting breakpoint on the model), setter of activeSetting variable does not hit.

```
<ComboBox 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={enums:Enumeration  {x:Type enums:Languages}, EnumNameUsage=UseLanguageResource}}" 
    DisplayMemberPath="Description" 
    SelectedValuePath="Value"  
    SelectedValue="{Binding ActiveSetting.Controller.Language}"/>
```

As I know that, SetProperty of BindableBase has propertyChanged event but I don't understand why it is not working.

Thanks for any info you can provide.

Edit: Let's say I have an string variable in my viewmodel and also I created textbox in my view. With binding text property of textbox Text={Binding mystringvariable}, I can reach if my string variable change or not from setter of string variable. However, if the binded variable is class object and binding is Text={Binding classobject.mystringvariable} I can't see if mystringvariable of classobject is changed or not from setter of classobject variable.

Comment: I don't know [tag:prism] at all, but are you actually setting ViewModel.ActiveSettings?  Or are you setting ViewModel.ActiveSettings.Controller.Language?

Comment: Yest I am setting ActiveSettings.Controller.Language but because the language variable is created as ActiveSettings' property, I want to get that if any changes is happened under ActiveSettings, I should learn it from setter of ActiveSettings. Controller should know if Language is changed or not and also ActiveSettings should know if Controller's property is changed or not

Answer (score 1):

> `SetProperty(ref _activeSetting, value)`

returns true if the value of `_activeSetting` is updated to a new instance. If you change a property on `ActiveSetting`, the setter isn't even called.

You want to have something like `ActiveSettingChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);` on every property on every object that may appear somewhere in a property of `ActiveSetting`.

Prism has a service called `EventAggregator` that you can use so to avoid having to subscribe to all those events on all those properties. Replace

```
ActiveSettingChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

with

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<ActiveSettingsChangedEvent>().Publish();
```

Of course, you need a `class ActiveSettingsChangedEvent : PubSubEvent` and you have to inject `IEventAggregator` where needed.

To subscribe, replace

```
_publisher.ActiveSettingsChanged += Handler;
```

with

```
_eventAggregator.GetEvent<ActiveSettingsChangedEvent>().Subscribe( Handler );
```

Comment: I think the problem is not about the event part. I have an SettingModel ActiveSetting object in my viewmodel and SettingModel includes objects from classes. I want to change the language of ActiveSetting variable from my view. If I create textbox in my view and bind text property like Text={binding mystringvariable} to string variable in my viewmodel, any change can be seen from setter of string variable. Actually, I want same thing when I use ActiveSetting variable.

Comment: I get that - your problem's that `{Binding ActiveSetting.Controller.Language}` means you don't change `ActiveSetting` and you never call `ActiveSetting`'s setter. You call the setter of `Language` within `Controller` within `ActiveSetting`.

Comment: Exactly.. Also there are many variable in Controller as Language. Beside this, there are more classes in SettingsModel(on the same level as Controller). I thought that I might create an event in SettingsModel and I can trigger it in the setter of Language and other variables which stands under Controller. However, it will not be suitable for the structure. Do you have any suggestion for it?

Comment: I'd abandon the native events and go for something more complex yet more suitable. You _could_ stick with native events, but `ActiveSettings` needs to subscribe to all his properties' values' events, and those to theirs, and you write hundreds of lines of boilerplate code just to forward the events. Plus thousands of lines of tests to make sure all events are attached and detached correctly and there are no leaks...